# Python - querying tables from database and having conditions in data frame

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I have made the connection to Teradata Database using :

```
import pyodbc 
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Teradata};DBCNAME="";UID="";PWD="";QUIETMODE=YES;')
```

Teradata has a customer table :

```
Customer ID , CreateDate
```

I need to run a query for a list of customers (stored in python list)

```
Select * from customer where Customer in (Python List)
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I've converted the list to a `tuple` so that it has round brackets to match the SQL syntax for an array instead of square brackets of a Python list:

```
import pandas as pd
query = "Select * from customer where Customer in {}".format(tuple(customerlist))    
df = pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```